Change in Gibbs energy for lithium redox reaction
I was reading an electrochemistry book by Thomas F. Fuller, in this book the thermodynamic  values for the lithium redox reaction at standard conditions are the following:



Reaction
$\Delta G^o$ [kJ/mol]




$\ce{Li -> Li+_{(aq)} + e-}$
-293.3



Applying the formula,
$$E^o = -\Delta G^o/nF $$
Results in, $E^o = 3.04$ for n=1.
This value is also listen in a table of standard potentials of the same book (and others).
I tried looking at JANAF tables, but I have failed to find a table that lists this value on the website, any advice?

So, you ask 'bout searching JANAF tables? BTW no big letters for elements, please.

Yes or find a similar source the does contain that value, mostly I want want to confirm if they don't have the value or how to properly search it on their tables. Apologies for the capitalization of the element, thank you for modifying the question.
